# How can I get rid of this error which I am getting with a code to find nearest neighbors?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science, knn

I have written the following function which takes data, number of peers to find, and index to find the top N nearest neighbors :

```
def fit_nearest_neighbors(data, number_of_peers, index):
    peer_data = FindPeers.filt_data(data)
    peer_data_array = np.array(peer_data)
    knn = NearestNeighbors(algorithm = 'auto', n_neighbors = number_of_peers, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
    knn.fit(peer_data_array)
    return knn.kneighbors(peer_data_array[index], return_distance = False)
```

But I am getting the following error with the last line of code after return which says :

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2.86839521e-01 7.63588709e-01 1.00000000e+00 1.73483898e-01
 0.00000000e+00 1.25068828e-02 1.66424454e-17 4.38357126e-01
 7.55219585e-03 6.03820534e-02 2.72387749e-01].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

The error array that It prints is basically the datapoint present at that particular `index`.
I understand the error but I don't understand how do I make it right. Any type of leads/answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You need to reshape your data from 1D to 2D using the numpy function `np.reshape()`.

You can accomplish this with

```
peer_data_array = np.array(peer_data).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Had it been only this, I would have done  it.

Comment: What is the shape of your array?